# Android Studio - Cannot Connect to Bluetooth Device

Tags: bluetooth, connection, device, connect

Well, I have everything set up to create a connection to another bluetooth device.
I have a ListView that shows me devices that are paired to my bluetooth device and when I click on the desired device within the listView it should connect to it, but somehow the connection is not being established.
Here is a sample of my paired devices List:

```c#
public void getPairedDevices(){
    pairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    pairedDevices_ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    if(pairedDevices.size()>0){
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices){
            pairedDevices_ArrayAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
        }
    }
    pairedDevices_ListView.setAdapter(pairedDevices_ArrayAdapter);
    pairedDevices_ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String i = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            String address = i.substring(i.length() - 17);
            deviceToConnectTo = myBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
            connectToDevice(deviceToConnectTo);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my `connectToDevice() void`:

```c#
public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device){
    try {
        mmSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    } catch (IOException e){}

    try{
        mmSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException e){
        showMsg("Error Connecting to device");
        try{
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException exception){}
    }
}
```

`showMsg` is basically a `Toast.makeText`, it keeps giving me "

> Error Connecting to device

toast message, which means that somehow it was impossible to connect.

Can someone tell me why?

I'm using API level 10 and trying to connect to HC-05 Bluetooth Module.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems I managed to fix the problem of not connecting to the HC-05 Bluetooth module. The problem was the UUID I was using.
I changed the UUID to:

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

It's used to bluetooth serial boards such as HC-05.

Comment: Where you find UUID String?

Comment: @lukecross it's the standard UUID to use when you're connecting to a [serial device via Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice).